# Go Cloud Development Kit Docstore: How to properly use a UUID for as the primary ID

Tags: go, go-cdk

I'm using use the [GoCDK](https://github.com/google/go-cloud) (**not** the AWS CDK) to abstract away infrastructure (EG: Use DynamoDB in AWS but use MongoDB for local iteration).

I want to store a document with a UUID as the primary key.

```golang
type PayloadItem struct {
    ID      uuid.UUID    `json:"id"`
    Time    time.Time    `json:"time"`
    Message *string      `json:"message,omitempty"`
    State   PayloadState `json:"state"`
}

func Save(payload PayloadItem) {
    if err := collection.Create(ctx, &payload); err != nil {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Testing this much with MongoDB works without issue. I can manually confirm with mongo-express that  the item is successfully created and stored.
[image: Image of mongo-express interface showing document with all fields populated]

When I try to retrieve the same item back, I run into issues with a runtime panic.

```golang
func Load(id uuid.UUID) {
    payload := lib.PayloadItem{
        ID: id,
    }
    if err := collection.Get(ctx, &payload); err != nil {
        // ...
```

From what I can tell, somewhere internal to the GoCDK, there is an attempt to hash the bytes of the UUID when it tries to assign it as a key in a `map`.

Attempting this instead returns that it cannot find the item.

```golang
func Load(id uuid.UUID) {
    payload := lib.PayloadItem{}
    iter := collection.Query().Where("ID", "=", id.String()).Limit(1).Get(ctx)
    defer iter.Stop()
    if err := iter.Next(ctx, &payload); err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            // We end up in this branch
```

What's the correct way to retrieve a document with a primary key with a UUID?

Answer (score 0):

- https://github.com/google/go-cloud/issues/2920 looks somewhat related and has some sample code using UUID and MongoDB that purportedly works.

If that doesn't help,

- Please consider filing a bug: https://github.com/google/go-cloud/issues/new/choose
- Can you share the code you use to create the `collection`?
- Does the same Create/Get work with other providers (e.g., `memdocstore`)?